# How to fetch correct UTC in system

Tags: linux, fedora, timezone

Did a fresh `Fedora 32` install **by erasing existing `Windows 10 Pro` installation completely**(*No dual boot here*). After installation, the display time is acting weird.

My local timezone is IST. That is, +5:30 from UTC. At `01:00PM`, my clock shows time as `6:30PM`. When I inspected the issue using `timedatectl` I saw that

Real Clock Time: 13:00 - IST
UTC: 13:00 - IST
Local Time - IST+05:30

```
$ timedatectl
     Local time: Thu 2020-07-30 18:30:40 IST
 Universal time: Thu 2020-07-30 13:00:40 UTC
       RTC time: Thu 2020-07-30 13:00:40
      Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)  
 System clock synchronized: no                         
    NTP service: inactive                   
RTC in local TZ: no
```

How to correct it?

Comment: This is already covered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91792/5132 , a general Q&A for these situations.

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit out of the question your main point, which was that you ran `ntpd` and `ntpdate` and they did not "fetch correct UTC".

Comment: ok will update.

Answer (score 1):

On your machine, you got a hardwareclock (RTC). Windows and Debian disagree, wheter that clock should be on UTC (Debian's oppinion) or on LT (Windows oppinion).

You should choose waht time on your hardwareclock should be and change it on the OS.

## RTC is LT

You have to change Debians setting. Run this command as root.

```
# timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

## RTC is UTC

I personally prefere that, because the clock never hase to jump, when you change the timezone for travelling or when you cnage to wintertime.

But you have to change settings in Windows. So you need the cmd running as administrator:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation" /v RealTimeIsUniversal /d 1 /t REG_QWORD /f
```

---

After you have fixed your settings, you can sync the time and the time will work fine.

[Source: ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_time)

Comment: It's easy to reach for the canned "You haven't used UTC for your hardware RTC." answer, but in this case the question outright tells us that the hardware RTC _is_ in UTC. The real problem here is that the questioner hasn't noticed an important paragraph in [the `ntpdate` manual](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ntpdate/ntpdate.8.en.html), and an important setting in [the `ntpd` manual](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ntp/ntpd.8.en.html) that applies to a clock that is 5.5 hours off.  This WWW site's general NTP Q&A already answers this.

Comment: @JdeBP: The question is (IMHO) unclear, and you and I are interpreting it differently. The problem is that the OP doesn’t say *what time it **really** is* when he runs the `timedatectl` command. Yes, it shows that the RTC time is *set to the same value that is displayed as UTC.* But the text says “Indian Standard Time (IST) is being incorrectly shown as Universal Time (UTC).” I interpret this to mean that he ran the command at 13:15 IST (local time), and so the RTC is set to local time (and the command is displaying local time incorrectly).

Comment: I will re-write the question. I am basically a Microsoft stack developer and a  noob with linux. Exploring .NET Core runtime.

Comment: The big clue, G-Man, was that the question was posted roughly half an hour after the local time given in (the original version of) the question.  (-:  The questioner has done everything right, set the hardware RTC to be interpreted as UTC and run an NTP client.  The NTP client simply _did not_ "fetch the correct UTC", which is in the question title and which is _exactly_ what is dealt with by the general NTP Q&A aforementioned.  UTC in the hardware clock is off by 5.5 hours (for obvious reasons) and neither `ntpd` nor `ntpdate` were willing to fix it by fetching the correct UTC.