# Wrong time on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, time

The system is located in Italy, and executing `date` gives `Fri  7 Aug 16:15:56 CEST 2020`, whereas the actual time is 14:21:09.

Executing `timedatectl status` gives:

```
               Local time: Fri 2020-08-07 16:15:56 CEST
           Universal time: Fri 2020-08-07 14:15:56 UTC 
                 RTC time: Fri 2020-08-07 14:15:57     
                Time zone: Europe/Rome (CEST, +0200)   
System clock synchronized: no                          
              NTP service: inactive                    
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

How can I fix show the correct time?

Arch is in dual boot with Windows 10 and I don't care if Windows shows the wrong time when I'll have the correct time on Arch.

Comment: Start your `ntp` service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you definately should set-up NTP (ArchWiki has an excellent article on the subject: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Time_Protocol_daemon#Configuration) you will continue to have problems because Windows assumes that the system clock should be local time and will keep adjusting it. Linux will continue to do it the other way around.

The solution to this is to reconfigure **one** of them. For example to tell Linux that the system clock is local, you can run this command:

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

The other way around, telling Windows to use UTC can be done by adding this registry entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal
```

Which should be DWORD (32) with a value of:

```
1
```

Comment: Is your second suggestion dependent on setting up NTP?

Comment: No, it will work without NTP, but it's still better to set-up NTP as well. Most computer clocks are not very reliable and if you end up using Linux a lot, it will keep drifting further away.

Comment: If you expect to use Linux more, I would suggest to change the Windows registry. If you want to change the time before setting NTP you can use the date command in Linux:

% sudo date -s "7 AUG 2020 15:05:00"

Comment: +1, and I will use Linux the most. I'll test the effect of changeing the registry on Windows soon enough and accept.

Comment: See the general NTP Q&A at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91792/5132 for the next part of the problem, which is `ntpd` refusing to correct errors that large.

Comment: Strangely I've found today again the wrong time, so I've run again the `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock` command, and checked that after reboot the time is still fine, so apparentry is something other than the reboot that reset the time to the wrong one. I'll monitor it for some time.