# Negative number in the last column of the "last" command

Tags: linux, command-line, last

Why do I have a negative number for system boot in the last (duration) column of the "last" command?[image]

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/605207/5132 , where the questioner is in Kolkata rather than Dubai or the Seychelles.  You should tell people your default timezone, how your RTC is being understood, and what system management toolset (systemd, runit, upstart, et al.) you are using with (say) the output of `timedatectl` or some such, [edit]ed into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The last column shows how long the user has logged in as a difference between login and logout time, negative time may be listed when the clocks were not in sync i.e. the date/time was incorrect when the time was logged.