# My harware clock is OK, but the system clock is not, and I cannot set it

Tags: arch-linux, timestamps, clock, artix-linux

From Linux, the `date --iso-8601=s` command returns:

> 2020-10-23T22:26:22+01:00

The timezone is correct, the UTC offset is correct (England, daylight saving time). However the clock is one hour ahead.

If I reboot in Windows, the time is correct.

Does this mean that the hardware clock is set correctly, and it is misread by Linux?

How can I fix this?

This command has no effect:  `sudo hwclock --systohc`

Comment: Linux expects the hardware clock to be set in UTC, Windows expects it to be set to local time.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605207/my-local-time-is-in-the-correct-timezone-but-isnt-actually-the-real-local-time should have the answer

Comment: @OskarSkog - Thank you for the link. If you put it as an answer I will accept it.